# Converting .pdf files to .docx or .doc

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any web app or website where I can upload a .pdf file and get it converted into .docx file or .doc file?

I have searched a lot, but all of them convert .pdf to .rtf and opening .rtf is a little difficult on Linux-based systems.

Comment: And if you open the .rtf with Google Docs and then save it as .docx? (I know you can import .docx files, I don’t know if you can export them as well with Google Docs.)

Comment: Why do you _need_ a `docx` file? Why not just a doc file? @Alex Docs doesn't support save as `docx`, `doc` files are supported \

Comment: @Sathya I have edited my question.

Comment: Then Google Docs becomes a real option: import the `rtf` file you already have in Google Docs and then save it on you computer as a Word (`doc`) file.

Comment: @Alex But isn't Google Docs famous for spoiling the formatting of .doc files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDF to Word](http://www.pdftoword.com/) can do this for you. I have used it myself previously.

Answer (score 2):

[Saaspose](http://saaspose.com) is the free online document converter that can not only convert Word document but also PDFs, emails and many other document to different formats and you can also create your document from the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to [www.zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com) and then upload the file, choose what you want to convert it to, then they'll send it to you through email.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs can perform an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) scan on-the-fly. It will create, from a PDF for example, a google doc file.

See reference: [Google Drive; OCR](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176692)